# How do I unequip the Spectre Cloak?

Tags: owlboy

The final item for collecting every Buccanary Coin is the Spectre Cloak, which powers up Otis's dash and spin attack. I want to disable the cloak effects, but I don't see an option to unequip it in the item menu.

Is there any way to unequip the Spectre Cloak once it's been unlocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to unequip the cloak. Go the Buccaneer's Shop, speak to the shopkeeper and choose the cloak from the list. The coat returns to its place in the shop, and you can re-equip it by speaking to the shopkeeper again.